What Makes Phase Type Distributions Interesting
I am studying phase type distributions in my introductory stochastic processes course. I understand what they are and how to calculate with them.
What I don't understand is, what makes them special? Why do we care about phase type distributions as their own things? Do they have mathematical properties that make them especially interesting or able to solve problems we otherwise couldn't?
